Demonstration of different Gaussian quadrature
I am doing demonstration about Gaussian quadrature.
Any supplementation would be greatly appreciated.
Related:

Gauss-Legendre and Gauss-Jacobi quadrature, in MATLAB

 
 
 
My question is:
The answer said adaptive Gauss–Kronrod quadrature formula may be the fastest.
Is there better-approximated quadrature method for these 2 kinds of numerical integrations: $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} f(x) \mathrm{d} x$ and $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \mathrm{d} x$
Gauss–Hermite quadrature Interval (-∞, +∞)
$$
{\displaystyle \int _{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx\approx \sum _{i=1}^{n}w_{i} \exp(x_i^2) \cdot f(x_{i})}
$$
Where $w_i=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } 2^{n-1} n!}{n^2 \text{PhysicitsHermitePolynomial}(n-1,{x_i})^2}$
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 20;
ProbabilistsHermitePolynomial[n_, x_] := 
 2^(-n/2)*HermiteH[n, x/Sqrt[2]] // Expand
PhysicitsHermitePolynomial[n_, x_] := HermiteH[n, x];
WeightForProbabilistsHermitePolynomial[xNode_] := Exp[-xNode^2/2];
WeightForPhysicitsHermitePolynomial[xNode_] := 
  2^(n - 1)*n!*
   Sqrt[Pi]/(n^2*(PhysicitsHermitePolynomial[n - 1, xNode])^2);
xNodes = x /. NSolve[PhysicitsHermitePolynomial[n, x], x];
wivec = WeightForPhysicitsHermitePolynomial[xNodes];
func[x_] := 1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*(Exp[-x^2/2]);
func[x_] := Exp[-x^6];
integral = NIntegrate[func[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
est1 = (wivec*Exp[xNodes^2]) . func[xNodes]

Generalized Gauss–Laguerre quadrature Interval (0, +∞)
$$
{\displaystyle \int _{0}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx\approx \sum _{i=1}^{n}w_{i}\frac{1}{x_i^a e^{-x_i}} \cdot f(x_{i})}
$$
Where $w_i=\frac{\Gamma (a+n+1)}{(x_i n!) L_{n-1}^{a+1}(x_i){}^2}$
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 100; a = -1/2;
laguerreNodes = x /. NSolve[LaguerreL[n, a, x], x];
wiVec = x |-> 
   Gamma[a + n + 1]/(n!    x)    1/LaguerreL[n - 1, a + 1, x]^2;
laguerreWeights = wiVec[laguerreNodes];
fun[x_] := Exp[-x^2];
integral = NIntegrate[fun[x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]
est1 = (laguerreWeights*Table[1/((x^a)*(E^-x)),{x,laguerreNodes}]) . fun[laguerreNodes]

Gauss–Legendre quadrature Interval [−1, 1]
$$
{\displaystyle \int _{-1}^{+1}f(x)\,dx\approx \sum _{i=1}^{n}w_{i}  \cdot f(x_{i})}
$$
Where $w_i=\frac{2}{\left(1-x_i^2\right) P_n^{\prime}(x_i)^2}$
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 10;
LegendreP1Derivative[n_, x_] := D[LegendreP[n, x], x];
xNodes = x /. NSolve[LegendreP[n, x] == 0, x];
wiVec[x_] := 2/((1 - x^2)*LegendreP1DerivativeAtNode[n, x]^2);
LegendreP1DerivativeAtNode[n_, xNode_] := 
  LegendreP1Derivative[n, x] /. x -> xNode;
myWeights = Map[wiVec, xNodes];
fun[x_] := Exp[-x^2];
integral = NIntegrate[fun[x], {x, -1, 1}]
est1 = myWeights . fun[xNodes]

Chebyshev–Gauss quadrature (first kind) Integral (-1, 1)
$$
{\displaystyle \int _{-1}^{+1}f(x)\,dx\approx \sum _{i=1}^{n}w_{i} \sqrt{1-x_i^2} \cdot f(x_{i})}
$$
Where $w_i=\pi/n$
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 40;
(*xNodes=Table[Cos[(2i-1)/(2n)*Pi],{i,1,n}]//N;*)
xNodes = x /. NSolve[ChebyshevT[n, x], x];
wiVec[x_] := Pi/n;
myWeights = Map[wiVec, xNodes];
fun[x_] := 1/Sqrt[1 - x^2];
integral = NIntegrate[fun[x], {x, -1, 1}]
est1 = (myWeights*Table[Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, xNodes}]) . fun[xNodes]

Chebyshev–Gauss quadrature (second kind) Integral [-1, 1]
$$
{\displaystyle \int _{-1}^{+1}f(x)\,dx\approx \sum _{i=1}^{n}w_{i}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x_i^2}}  \cdot f(x_{i})}
$$
Where ${\displaystyle w_{i}={\frac {\pi }{n+1}}\sin ^{2}\left({\frac {i}{n+1}}\pi \right).\,}$
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 40;
(*xNodes=Table[Cos[i*Pi/(n+1)],{i,1,n}]//N;*)
xNodes = x /. NSolve[ChebyshevU[n, x], x];
myWeights = Table[Pi/(n + 1)*Sin[i*Pi/(n + 1)]^2, {i, 1, n}];
fun[x_] := Exp[-x^2];
integral = NIntegrate[fun[x], {x, -1, 1}]
est1 = (myWeights*Table[1/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, xNodes}]) . fun[xNodes]

Gauss–Jacobi quadrature Interval (-1, 1) not sure, can be refined more
$$
{\displaystyle \int _{-1}^{+1} (1-x)^{\alpha}(1+x)^{\beta}  f(x)\,dx\approx \sum _{i=1}^{n}w_{i}  \cdot f(x_{i})} \quad \alpha,\beta > -1
$$
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 20;
a = 1/3;
b = 2/3;
xNodes = x /. NSolve[JacobiP[n, a, b, x] == 0, x];
myGamma[n_] := 
  NIntegrate[(1 - x)^a*(1 + x)^b*JacobiP[n - 1, a, b, x]^2, {x, -1, 
    1}];
JacobiPDerivative1[n_, a_, b_, xInstance_] := 
  D[JacobiP[n, a, b, x], x] /. {x -> xInstance};
Afunction[n_, a_, b_, xInstance_] := 
  Coefficient[JacobiP[n, a, b, x], x, n] /. {x -> xInstance};
wiVec[x_] := 
  Afunction[n, a, b, x]*
   myGamma[n]/(Afunction[n - 1, a, b, x]*
      JacobiPDerivative1[n, a, b, x]*JacobiP[n - 1, a, b, x]);
myWeights = Map[wiVec, xNodes];
fun[x_] := Exp[-x^4];
integral = NIntegrate[((1 + x)^a*(1 - x)^b)*fun[x], {x, -1, 1}]
est1 = myWeights . fun[xNodes]

Gauss–Jacobi quadrature Interval (a, b)
Reference code
Any help would be appreciated.

